# HTML Textarea horizontal scroll

Tags: html, textarea, word-wrap

I would like to provide a horizontal scroll to a textarea in my HTML page. The scroll should appear without wrapping, if I type a long line without a line break. A few friends suggested using overflow-y CSS attribute, which did not work for me. The browsers that I use are IE 6+ and Mozilla 3+.

Comment: `<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To set no wrapping, you would use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

For other values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

NOTE: However the depreciated `wrap="off"` seems to be the only way for legacy browser support. Though it isn't HTML 5 compliant, it's still my preference if you're targeting all browsers.

Comment: This doesn't work. It puts all text, including multiple lines, on the same line, not the desired behavior.

Comment: To see new lines properly, you must use `white-space: pre;`.

Answer (score 108):

I figured out to do it in a non-W3c-compliant way and it is working in both IE and Firefox and incidentally in Chrome too.

I added the attribute `wrap` with value `off`, that is `<textarea cols=80 rows=12 wrap='off'>` is what I have done.

Comment: The correct way to do this is via CSS as [Aram Kocharyan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5104505/238722) points out. `off` is not a valid or recognized value of the `<textarea>` attribute `wrap`.

Answer (score 24):

If you have pre-formatted text that includes LFs, you should add `white-space: pre;` to the css. That will preserve the new lines that are already in the text and will not wrap long lines.

This works in all versions of Firefox, all Webkit-based browsers, and IE6+.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 5):

Try these:

```
overflow: scroll; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: scroll; 
overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical;
```

there should also be a -moz-scrollbars-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: pre;` as CSS property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space