# Baffling JavaScript behavior when inserting text after document.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot wrap my head around this. I want to duplicate the text that's just been written and insert it at the cursor point. `span.className='newSpan'` gets inserted correctly as a span, but then adding `span.innerHTML=content` afterwards removes the span. Other combinations have resulted in a "Failed to execute 'insertNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'" error.

```
if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            var cursor = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var content = document.getSelection().anchorNode.data
            var span = document.createElement("span")
            span.className = 'newSpan'
            // and what I'd basically like to do:
            span.innerHTML = content
            cursor.insertNode(span)
```

Attempting to do something like `$('.newSpan').text(content)` afterwards also doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and complete JavaScript so that we can execute your code and replicate your issue as well as provide you with a working answer.

Comment: inner HTML includes the span container... of course overwriting it would remove the tag.

Comment: obviously innerHTML would mean the outer HTML was overwritten, obviously. Any attempt at doing jQuery style '.html(content)' has failed on my part. So, is there a way to add text or html to a span in such a way?

Comment: checkout examples from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript

Comment: Thanks num8er but I'm getting a 'Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of null' error. Without the line the span gets created, so I don't know what could be 'null'.