# Add Text to TextArea Where Cursor is currently in position Trigger By Shortcut Key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to two `textarea` each with same `button` class `.addText`. I am trying insert word `hello world` to the `textarea` where the cursor in, this event would trigger via shortcut key `ctrl` + `i`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      $(".addText").trigger("click");
      event.preventDefault();

    }
  })

  $('.addText').click(function() {
    // Add Text 'hello world' to input textarea that curssor currently in
    $(this).next().val('hello world');
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Include BS and FA -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="ta1">
        <button class="addText">Add Text</button>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="inputTa1"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="ta1">
        <button class="addText">Add Text</button>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="inputTa2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, Currently, the word `hello world` is inserted into both textarea when shortcut key `ctrl` + `i` is pressed.

I could not differentiate which textarea cursor is currently in, I found one source here: [Insert text into textarea at cursor position (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript), but it does not apply to my case.

How can I check which textarea that has cursor in and apply an action to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do the reverse of your button click.

Instead of doing `next`,  do `prev` on the target element.

eg.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(event.target).prev().trigger("click");
    }
  })

  $('.addText').click(function() {
    // Add Text 'hello world' to input textarea that curssor currently in
    $(this).next().val('hello world');
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Include BS and FA -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="ta1">
        <button class="addText">Add Text</button>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="inputTa1"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="ta1">
        <button class="addText">Add Text</button>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="inputTa2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thtanks very much