# How do I prevent the cursor in Chrome's textarea from jumping to the top when the user inserts a newline in the middle of a long text?

Tags: html, google-chrome, textarea

If you have a `<textarea>` with a lot of text (i.e. more than twice the height of the textarea), when the user inserts a newline in the middle, Chrome scrolls the text such that the cursor is at the top of the `<textarea>`. This behavior is disorienting for the user, as they must manually scroll the textarea in order to bring content from above back into view. Neither Firefox nor Safari has this behavior.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a `<textarea>`
2. Paste a lot of text into it
3. Put the cursor in the middle of the text
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Expected behavior:
The relative position of the cursor in the textarea remains the same.

Actual behavior:
The text scrolls such that the cursor is at the top of the text area.

To reiterate, this behavior does **not** occur with Safari or Firefox. It's specific to Chrome.

Is there any way to suppress this behavior in Chrome and get it to behave more like Firefox and Safari?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this problem. Also saw this post reporting a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329625/preventing-textarea-scroll-behaviour-in-chrome-after-newline-added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

1. [Detect Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618)
2. [Count how many line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950538/how-to-detect-line-breaks-in-a-text-area-input) are used in the textarea
3. Before input, check the scroll position of the textarea
4. After `input`, see if the number of line breaks has increased (i.e. has the user entered a line break). If so, then reset the scroll position.

(Note: `beforeinput` event is already [supported by Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event#Browser_compatibility), but [assumed not to be supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinput) by Chrome for iOS, so in that case `scroll` event can be used. If you prefer, you can simply enable the scroll event for all cases.)

```js
function getChromeType() {
  //source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618
  // please note, 
  // that IE11 now returns undefined again for window.chrome
  // and new Opera 30 outputs true for window.chrome
  // but needs to check if window.opr is not undefined
  // and new IE Edge outputs to true now for window.chrome
  // and if not iOS Chrome check
  // so use the below updated condition
  var isChromium = window.chrome;
  var winNav = window.navigator;
  var vendorName = winNav.vendor;
  var isOpera = typeof window.opr !== "undefined";
  var isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
  var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

  if (isIOSChrome) {
    // is Google Chrome on IOS
    return 1;
  } else if (
    isChromium !== null &&
    typeof isChromium !== "undefined" &&
    vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
    isOpera === false &&
    isIEedge === false
  ) {
    // is Google Chrome
    return 2;
  } else {
    // not Google Chrome 
    return 0;
  };
};

function handleChromeTextarea(el, useScroll) {
  let getNoLineBreaks = () => {
    //source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950538/how-to-detect-line-breaks-in-a-text-area-input
    return (el.value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;
  };

  let getScrollPos = () => {
    return el.scrollTop;
  };

  let onInput = (e) => {
    const newNoLineBreaks = getNoLineBreaks();

    if (noLineBreaks < newNoLineBreaks) {
      el.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    };

    noLineBreaks = newNoLineBreaks;
  };

  let onBeforeInput = (e) => {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  };

  let noLineBreaks = getNoLineBreaks();
  let scrollPos = getScrollPos();

  el.addEventListener("input", onInput);
  el.addEventListener("beforeinput", onBeforeInput); //Already supported by Chrome - you may wish to use this without the scroll event

  if (useScroll) {
    el.addEventListener("scroll", onBeforeInput);
  };
};


const chromeType = getChromeType();

if (0 < chromeType) {
  handleChromeTextarea(document.getElementById("textarea"), (chromeType === 1));
};
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Massa eget egestas purus viverra. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh.

Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa.

Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Pretium lectus quam id leo. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. Sem et tortor consequat id.

Mi sit amet mauris commodo. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis.

Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec. Fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet. Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo. Proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra. Quam quisque id diam vel. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
</textarea>
```