# Is it possible to simulate keyboard presses into input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It is necessary to simulate the keystrokes in the input. Yes, I know that I can change data via input, but this does not suit me.

I tried through KeyboardEvents, but it doesn’t work.

```
const ke = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 50
});

document.body.dispatchEvent(ke);
```

Comment: What if you add the key down event on the document.body. eg. document.body.addEventListener('keydown', callbackFunction)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you need to simulate keyboard events? Maybe you just need to insert text in a way that more or less preserve the ctrl + z history: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/how-to-insert-text-into-the-textarea-at-the-current-cursor-position

Comment: The keystroke itself occurs, but no characters are added in the input. I need this for my extension for Chrome to change the data in one input site. The site has an unusual input, when I try to change the data through the .value nothing happens. Only keyboard input works. Sorry my bad english