# Enter text into textinput by clicking button into where the cursor is

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have an `input` with some buttons that enters text into it;

```
<input id="input"/>
<button onclick="enter('a')">a</button>
<button onclick="enter('b')">b</button>
<button onclick="enter('c')">c</button>

<script>
function enter(character){
document.getElementById("input").value+=character;
document.getElementById("input").focus();
}
</script>
```

I want to make these buttons enter `a`, `b` and `c` where the cursor blinks, not at the back at the whole text. What script is needed to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Ok, so you want only have  one latter at a time.?

Comment: @DipankarMaikap well, one button click only enters one letter at a time, so yes, although `a` `b` `c` are only sample texts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/how-to-insert-text-into-the-textarea-at-the-current-cursor-position

Comment: [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150864/10078895) could be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064089/12860895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code snippet; this is all the code you need:

```js
function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
  if (!txtarea) {
    return;
  }

  var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
  var strPos = 0;
  var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
  }

  var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
  var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
  txtarea.value = front + text + back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var ieRange = document.selection.createRange();
    ieRange.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    ieRange.moveStart('character', strPos);
    ieRange.moveEnd('character', 0);
    ieRange.select();
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
  }

  txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

```html
<input id="textareaid" />

<button onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', 'a');return false;">a</button>

<button onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', 'b');return false;">b</button>

<button onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', 'c');return false;">c</button>
```

<sub><sup>Source: [Inserting a text where cursor is using Javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064089/12860895)</sup></sub>