# Paste image, convert to base64 tag directly onto <textinput>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

### friendly notice: this question is a bit long.

#### [codepen](https://jstrieb.github.io/urlpages/editor/#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)

The following is a tool which converts image into base64 markdown image tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<textarea readonly placeholder="Base64 data" id="b64" rows="1" style="width:110px"></textarea>
<button onclick="enterBase64()">enter</button>
```

1. When a user pastes an image onto a certain location (*where the cursor is blinking*) in the `<textinput id="input">`, the image's data gets converted into base64 data and is shown in `<textinput id="b64">`,
2. and by clicking the `<button>`,  `![](` and `)` gets added to the back and front of the entire base64 data and gets pasted into `<textinput id="input">` at the previously selected location.

now here are the scripts;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').on('paste', function(e) {
    var orgEvent = e.originalEvent;
    for (var i = 0; i < orgEvent.clipboardData.items.length; i++) {
      if (orgEvent.clipboardData.items[i].kind == "file" && orgEvent.clipboardData.items[i].type == "image/png") {
        var imageFile = orgEvent.clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function() {
          $('#b64').html(fileReader.result);
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile); break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

(copied and edited from [How do i get base64 encoded image from clipboard in internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644340/how-do-i-get-base64-encoded-image-from-clipboard-in-internet-explorer)
)

this converts the pasted image into base64 data,

```
function enterBase64() {
insertAtCaret('input', "![](" + document.getElementById("b64").value + ")");return false;
}
```

this adds `![](` and `)` at the front and back and then pastes the result to `<textinput id="input">`,

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
  if (!txtarea) {
    return;
  }
  var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
  var strPos = 0;
  var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
  }
  var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
  var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
  txtarea.value = front + text + back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var ieRange = document.selection.createRange();
    ieRange.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    ieRange.moveStart('character', strPos);
    ieRange.moveEnd('character', 0);
    ieRange.select();
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
  }
  txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

(copied and edited from [Enter text into textinput by clicking button into where the cursor is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64404655/enter-text-into-textinput-by-clicking-button-into-where-the-cursor-is)
)

and this enables a desired text pasted onto the desired location in `<textinput id="input">` by clicking the button.

Basically, the tool works fine, but it requires two steps as stated above. My aim here is to make this process into one: **To paste an image onto `<textinput id="input">` and have its base64 markdown image data tag onto the cursor's location.** `<textinput id="b64">` and the `button` is no longer needed this way.

So how can I combine the second and third chunks of javascript into one and achieve this function?