# jQuery .change() does not work on the HTML text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#test').change(function(){
    $('#taskMessage').val($('#taskMessage').val()+" "+$('#test option:selected').text());
});
</script>


**<textarea class="summernote" id="taskMessage" name="taskMessage" data-plugin-summernote data-plugin-options='{ "height": 200, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($taskMessage); ?></textarea>**
```

What is the method to add the `selected:option` to the `id:taskMessage` . if simple `textarea` is added with the following code it works fine `<textarea id="taskMessage"></textarea>` but with the HTML editor it does not add the `selected:option` to the HTML text editor.

Comment: You are handling the change event for Select, not for the text area, it's not related to the problem, it works fine anyway,. the problem is in setting the value to the editor, for the normal `textarea` you use `.val()` and it works fine as you mentioned,  so you just need to check how to set a value for your editor correctly

Comment: @Zac thanks ;-( unfortunately, am bad in jQuery What should be the setting that can do the magic ?

Comment: it depends on the plugin that you use for the HTML editor, you need to read the documentation or specs of this plugin and search how to set a value dynamically using JavaScript

Comment: `<script>
$('#texteditor_selection').change(function(){
$('#taskMessage').code($('#taskMessage').code()+" "+$('#texteditor_selection option:selected').text());
});
</script>` 
>> this code works. How can I add the code that can add the tag on place where the mouse cursor. e.g if i add something it adds at the end of the paragraph. however if it add the tag at where the cursor is blinking will make my code perfect

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/how-to-insert-text-into-the-textarea-at-the-current-cursor-position

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the value and it's work fine. check it here:

```html
<select id="test">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<textarea class="summernote" id="taskMessage" name="taskMessage" data-plugin-summernote data-plugin-options='{ "height": 200, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'>hi I'm the textarea</textarea>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#test').change(function(){
    const selectValue = $('#test option:selected').text();
    const textValue = $('#taskMessage').val();
    console.log(textValue);
    $('#taskMessage').val(textValue+" "+ selectValue);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) but am not able to see the Bar and Foo in the HTML editor. `<textarea class="summernote" id="taskMessage" name="taskMessage" data-plugin-summernote data-plugin-options='{ "height": 200, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($taskMessage); ?></textarea>`

Comment: @Waqas check it again, I've edited the answer

Comment: @Waqas Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

it worked by using .code

```
$('#taskMessage').code($('#taskMessage').code()+" "+$('#texteditor_selection option:selected').text());
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this css and check because your code is working fine as expected

**CSS**

```css
textarea{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
resize:none;
}
```

Comment: if I add the code the editor goes away and convert to the simple textarea. however if I manually add the textarea it works. so it means  that the jquery is fine. as the above code works fine, but does not work with the HTML rich text editor. Either it could be conflicting the jQuery.

Comment: This is a css code. It would help you to see that your code is working fine and when there is a change in the dropdown value, your textarea value get also updated.