# inserting text in current (or last) caret position inside of TextArea, in Angular; Element is not interpreted as TextArea

Tags: angular, textarea, copy-paste

I was checking this documentation...

https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/examples

Is there some example explaining how to paste inside some text of the last current (maybe starting, or middle) position inside of `TextArea` (after of lost focus event).

I was trying with this simple response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58356806/5113188

```
function insertAtCaret(text) {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
  textarea.setRangeText(
    text,
    textarea.selectionStart,
    textarea.selectionEnd,
    'end'
  )
}

setInterval(() => insertAtCaret('Hello'), 3000)
```

Adapting to my code:

In .html file:

```
    <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="onInsertSomethingText(entry)" >
      <mat-icon>play_for_work</mat-icon>
    </button>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea
        [id]="BODY_TEXTAREA"
        matInput
        rows="5"
        formControlName="body"
      ></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

In my .ts file

```
  public readonly BODY_TEXTAREA = 'BODY_TEXTAREA';
  
  private buildMyFormGroup() {
    return internalFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      body: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
    });
  }
   
  //Event in ordfer to insert the text in the position!!!!
  public onInsertSomethingText(myText: string) {
    console.log(myText);
    const myTA = document.querySelector(this.BODY_TEXTAREA);
    myTA.setRangeText(myText, myTA.selectionStart, myTA.selectionEnd, 'end');
  }
```

In this line `myTA.setRangeText(myText, myTA.selectionStart, myTA.selectionEnd, 'end');` I'm obtaining these:

- Property 'setRangeText' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
- Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
- Property 'selectionEnd' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)

I know that possibly, the `myTA` is not interpreted as a real `TextArea`

**How to do it correctly?**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your id is MY_TEXTAREA and you are selecting BODY_TEXTAREA, is this a typo in the question?

Comment: @OwenKelvin thanks, you're al right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with Angular you're in TypeScript world.

`document.querySelector` method is a generic method where by default it returns `Element`:

```
querySelector<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E | null;
```

Simply choose the proper type and you're done:

```
const myTA = document.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>(`#${this.BODY_TEXTAREA}`);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I getting null in `myTA` variable then I can't test it. I know that is a change in the question.  I'm so sorry, :(

Comment: @Anita Can you please prepare a stackblitz example so I can help?

Comment: Sure!!!   Here my attempt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eenyyo

Comment: Since you're selecting by id you should be adding `#` before selector `document.querySelector('#${this.BODY_TEXTAREA}')` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nr6ngv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `const myTA = document.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>('#'+ this.BODY_TEXTAREA);`

Comment: @Anita Yes, that's the same

Comment: The single quote doesn't work I need to use backticK!

Comment: @Anita They should work. You're doing smth wrong. Please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmnksm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts