# Textarea word wrap only on line breaks

Tags: html, textarea, overflow, whitespace, line-breaks

So, I have a textarea that is filled with text from the DB for the user to edit.  The text from the DB contains line breaks in it (\r\n).  I would the textarea to only line wrap on line breaks.  I've messed around with different `white-space` attributes, but none seem to work.  Right now, I have:

```
textarea
{
    width: 60em;
    height: 40em;
    white-space: pre-line;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It does break on the line breaks, BUT ALSO breaks when the text on a line goes longer than 60em.  How do I get it to only break on line breaks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424192/html-textarea-horizontal-scroll

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get this to work in IE9.  None of the answers in that link worked for me.

Comment: The approved answer to the old question mentioned, the `wrap=off` attribute, is supported by all IE versions since IE 4.

Comment: Sorry, the wrap="off" did work.  I mistakenly tested it out on a different field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As andi pointed out, the answer is here: [HTML Textarea horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424192/html-textarea-horizontal-scroll)

```
<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```