# how to scroll textarea horizontally in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll input field .So I googled I found that we can't scroll input field , But we can do scroll text area horizontally.can you suggest how we scroll text area ?
Can we use iscroller   in that ?

Comment: task complete check out the fiddle..http://jsbin.com/OHaNENu/3/edit

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424192/html-textarea-horizontal-scroll

Comment: it is not working in android

Comment: in Chromium : SHIFT + mousescroll [not in FF, sorry ;(  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<textarea cols=80 rows=12 wrap='off'>
```