# Horizontal textarea scrollbar can't be grabbed in Chrome when border-radius is applied

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/h4myo11L/4/

```
<textarea wrap="off" rows="5" style="border-radius: 4px">aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
  aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
  aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
</textarea>
```

1. Scroll to the middle of textbox
2. Try to grab horizontal scrollbar with a mouse
3. You can't, it is a text cursor and it blinks behind the bar!

Remove border-radius style and repeat: now you can grab the horizontal scrollbar. It also starts working once you scroll to the very bottom.

Works fine in Firefox. I use wrap attribute instead of CSS because it's the only cross-browser compatible way including IE11 ([HTML Textarea horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424192/html-textarea-horizontal-scroll)). Using CSS resulted in return key being pressed in IE11 to produce a space instead of newline.

Is there any way to fix this in Chrome?

edit: Bug fixed in Chrome 52

Comment: i think you can report this as a bug in chrome community. i think they can fix it https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: I might. I just want to know if there is a workaround for this problem because I can't wait for Chrome to come around and fix it.

Comment: add textarea{position: relative;} this seems to fix it

Comment: On Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m Win10 it works ok.

Comment: I just had it happen to me without the border radius

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chromium 54.0.2792.0, Win 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• **OPTION 1:**

I have faced the exact same problem before and I have come up with a solution which is not the most professional one, but does the job for me.

First of all, wrap your **`textarea`** inside a **`div`** and set for your **`div`** the following properties:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid rgb(169,169,169);  /* The default color for the textearea's border */
    border-radius: 4px;                /* The border-radius you had on the text area */
    overflow: hidden;                /* To prevent the textarea's edges from overflowing */
    display: inline-block;       /* To ensure the div's border wraps around the textarea */
}
```

Then, remove the border from the **`textarea`** and set **`vertical-align: top`** to get rid of that sort of **`padding-bottom`** that exists in elements with **`display: inline-block`**. Like so:

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: top; /* To remove the small gap that exists in inline-block elements */
    border: 0;    /* To remove the border from the textarea */
}
```

As I said at the beginning, **I don't consider this a very professional approach and alternative to this bug**, but the result is visually identical to the **`textarea`** in your fiddle. However, **use it with caution** as it's likely that it may behave unexpectedly in some situations.

**Working fiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4myo11L/6/).

**Snippet:**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-x: visible;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea wrap="off" rows="5">aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
    IT'S 2016 AND I CANT EVEN HAVE A HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR ON A TEXTBOX.
  </textarea>
</div>
```

---

• **OPTION 2:**

After some tests, I found that, for some reason, setting **`position: relative`** to the **`textarea`** seems to **solve the issue as well**, at least in my version of Chrome, but **in case you want to use another type of positioning**, the above will do the job.

Comment: It is a genius hack but I don't think I'd ever use it, just feels too dirty. Relative positioning does indeed seem to work and I think it could be the right soution since it can be used in most cases without problem. Thank you for now.

Comment: Glad I could help @cen :)

Comment: Do you mean `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 3):

As said in my comment `position:relative;` fixes the issue with the scrollbar.

Another option you could try is to set the `border` to none and use `box-shadow` instead to give close to the same effect

I've included three examples in this fiddle of the different options to try: https://jsfiddle.net/p6jw6qvf/

```
#one{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #9a9a9a;
}

#two{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Note: if you go with option #two this positions the scrollbars ontop and causes them to sit over the border see image, to fix this you can use custom scrollbars to add border-radius to the scrollbar itself.

[image]